# Database running well on pc bt not on devices

Tags: android

I am making a quiz application. The database created for questions is working on pc but when I transfer the .apk file in the android phone it is not taking any data from the database and showing a force close.

After searching on this site I found to put the database file in asset folder but that didn't work.

I am not able to recognize why the application not running in the cellphone?
below is the code for the database file. Do let me know if there is any chances to be made in it to run the application on devises.

```
public class DatabaseFile extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.quizproject/databases/";
public static final String DATABASE_NAME="Quiz.db";
public static final String QUES="ques";
public static final String OP1="op1";
public static final String OP2="op2";
public static final String OP3="op3";
public static final String ANS="ans";
public static final String NAME="name";
public static final String CANS="cans";
public static final String SCORE="score";
private final Context myContext;
private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase; 

public DatabaseFile(Context context) {

super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
this.myContext = context;
}

public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

     boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

     if(dbExist){
      //do nothing - database already exist
     }else{
         this.getReadableDatabase();

         try {

       copyDataBase();

      } catch (IOException e) {

          throw new RuntimeException(e);

         }
     }

    }

    private boolean checkDataBase(){

     SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

     try{
      String myPath = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
      checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,   SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

     }catch(SQLiteException e){

      //database does't exist yet.

     }

     if(checkDB != null){

      checkDB.close();

     }

     return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

     //Open your local db as the input stream
     InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);

     // Path to the just created empty db
     String outFileName = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;

     //Open the empty db as the output stream
     OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

     //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
     byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
     int length;
     while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
      myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
     }

     //Close the streams
     myOutput.flush();
     myOutput.close();
     myInput.close();

    }

    public void openDataBase() {

     //Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
     myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    }
    @Override
     public synchronized void close() {
             if(myDataBase != null)
              myDataBase.close();
             super.close();
     }
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

//db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE quiztable (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
    //  "ques TEXT, op1 TEXT, op2 TEXT, op3 TEXT, ans TEXT);");




}



@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

Comment: There are no such errors. the application is running well on pc but not on android phones... how can we see logcat errors in smartphones??

Comment: The easiest way is tether your device to your computer with a USB cable and run your app via your IDE (like Eclipse). Similar to the way you debug with the emulator.

Comment: ok thanx for replying .. i will try and let you know whether it worked or not.